# Text Box like a underline

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox

Is there any way to make a textbox in asp.net control appear like a underline only, just like in paper documents where blanks are placed for text input?

Comment: why do you want to do this. for printing purpose?

Comment: @krshekhar If it was for printing purposes it wouldn't need to be a `TextBox` in the first place..

Comment: @Curt why some one would like to show a text-box like this. There must be some specific purpose.

Comment: @krshekhar Because they want to give the appearance of it being underlined like a paper document I guess. Its just design preference.

Comment: @Curt I have never seen such text-box in use. I may be wrong but I think it is for printing purpose only.

Comment: @krshekhar OK, well either way my solution should be "print friendly"

Comment: @krshekhar: If we only ever designed things as we have seen them before, then technology would never evolve

Comment: I wanted to make the webpage look just like a paper document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apply a solid `border-bottom`:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server" CssClass="underlined" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input.underlined
{
   border:0;
   border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
   outline:none; /* prevents textbox highlight in chrome */
}
```

[**-- SEE WORKING DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hpvQ/3/)

Comment: jsfiddle.net is a great website!!!! Thanks you for introducing this site to me!!!

Comment: Thanks, just what i wanted

Comment: In chrome (and maybe other browsers) you get a highlight, which in my opinion doesn't look nice with the "underline" style. Perhaps it is worth mentioning the `outline:none;` CSS style that can remove this (if desired)

Comment: @musefan Cheers, youre exactly right! I've added this to the answer.

Comment: This solution does not work and the 'working demo' is not an asp:TextBox but a <input type="text" />

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to change it on printing only then you should use like this

**For normal screen**

```
@media screen
{
   input.underlined
   {
    /*put your attributes here*/
   }
}
```

**for print screen**

```
@media print
{
  input.underlined
  {
    border:0;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
   }
}
```